# Visual Studio throwing an error my double quotes in my verbatim string for no reason?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Recently, Visual Studio said my string had an error. It said it needed a semicolon, but this error was referring to a part with double quotes and a letter.

```
string test = @"import os

f = open(""" + hash0 + ".exe"",""w+"")";
```

[Errors in Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZybCP.png)

Comment: The only problem I can see is the missing (typo) `@` before `".exe`

Comment: *"in my verbatim string"* - The code shown has two string literals.  Only the first one is a verbatim string.  The error is happening in the second one.

Comment: "for no reason" is really the wrong attitude to take with programming. This are going to go wrong, and it's almost always your fault. Learning to debug your program is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of you string concat sould have a `@` aswel

```
string test = @"import os
f = open(""" + hash0 + @".exe"",""w+"")";
```